# Meaning of my BigCommerce API error message

Tags: api, bigcommerce

What does the error "The quantity specified is greater than the quantity of the product that is available to ship." for my BigCommerce order mean?

Comment: Ehm, not sure how to say it better... The message is self-explanatory.

Comment: My code was working before without any error. I am getting this error recently though i have changed nothing. I am so confused.

Comment: If the same code is exectuded in an isolated environment, e.g. no external requests, updates, etc. then it must return the same results. Apparently, something has changed.

Answer (score 1):

[You can find your answer here](https://help.shipstation.com/hc/en-us/articles/206639607-What-does-the-error-The-quantity-specified-is-greater-than-the-quantity-of-the-product-that-is-available-to-ship-for-my-BigCommerce-order-mean-)

In brief it is caused by placing an order greater than the stock currently available in the inventory. This can be rectified by cancelling and replacing the order through the BigCommerce store. Below is a direct quote from the article on how to do this.

> If you want to try to clear this error message, you will need to login to your BigCommerce store, and increase the inventory amount for the product(s) you are trying to ship.
>
> Once you've done that, you can click on the red shipping cart icon for the shipment in the Shipments screen and Retry Failed Steps to re-send the information to your BigCommerce store.